# Jquery validation for mobile serial number

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I need jquery validation for the mobile serial number of each digits entered by user in the below formats

Sample1: `T1211WWDNNNNNNN`

Sample2: `T1211081NNNNNN`

Sample3: `T5511BJ316A1400001`

i have tried the below code. I need to validate each digit.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("customserial", function(value, element) {  
    if (/^[0-9A-Z]{4}(\-[0-9A-Z]{4})(\-[0-9A-Z]{4})(\-[0-9A-Z]{4})(\-[0-9A-Z]{4})$/.test(value)) {       
        return true; // pass when validation is correct
    } else {
        return false; // fail when validation fails
    };
}, "Please enter a valid Serial Number.");
```

Comment: is there any pattern regarding the mobile serial number

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please provide a sample of your code so we can see what's up.

Comment: http://imei-number.com/check-digit-calculation/ please follow the pattern regarding the checking the digit calculation